# Using a straight line in ScatterPlot Coreplot iOS

Tags: ios, line, core-plot, cgcontext

I'm trying to draw a graph using the coreplot library. I'm looking for a way to change the dataLineStyle of the graph so that all the dots will be connected in a straight line, without any playful turns. If needed, I can provide more information.

Is there any way to achieve this?

[EDIT]
I have included a picture to better understand what I'm talking about. I would not like the Graph Line to go above or under the data points.

[image: Coreplot graph with lines]

Comment: Are you trying to draw a regression (trend) line?

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to connect the dots by straight lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regression lines aren't built into Core Plot. You can use one scatterplot to draw the data points with just plot symbols and no data line. Use a second scatter plot to draw the regression line. It only needs two data points, one for each end of the line. You'll have to compute the regression coefficients yourself.

---

The lines connecting the data points are controlled by the `interpolation` property. The default is `CPTScatterPlotInterpolationLinear` which is what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I actually mean something else. Since I can't post pictures in this comment, I will edit my original question.